# Why convolution output size is different using Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: convolution, toeplitz

From CNN, 2D Convolution output size is (Input height - Kernel height + 1) * (Input width - Kernel width + 1), where padding = 0 and stride = 1. I was trying to find how to compute a convolution operation with "matrix multiplication", and the solution was to use a doubly block circulant matrix. Reading a few posts about how to implement doubly block circulant matrix, I realize that they have used a different way in computing the convolution size: (Input height + Kernel height - 1) * (Input width + Kernel width - 1). Can you give me an insight into why they use the different computation for the convolution output size?

Source: [Source1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35376), [Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865516/10798490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

> In mathematics, convolution is a mathematical operation on two functions ($f$ and $g$) that produces a third function ($f ∗ g$).

If you look carefully, you'll find that there are no real boundaries in the mathematical definition of a convolution — i.e., theoretically there is an output for every pixel index (cf. infinite zero-padding). However, since most of these outputs would be zero anyway (the kernel does not overlap with the actual image), these are generally ignored in the context of signal processing.

Now, in a general signal processing context, the output of the convolution is considered to be every output for which the value is non-zero. This corresponds to padding the input with $K-1$ zeros. In the context of neural networks, on the other hand, a lot of non-zero outputs are effectively ignored by using no (or little) input padding.

The sources you linked to talk about convolutions in the context of signal processing, **not** in the context of neural networks, which explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr. Tsjolder. Can I ask a question about your answer? Why every non-zero output corresponds to padding with the input with K-1 zeros. Shouldn't it be 2*(K-1) because zero padding has to be added to top and bottom (not considering left and right for now). Let's say we have two matrices: f:3x3 and g:2x2 . The non-zero output shouldn't be 5x5 instead of 4x4?

Comment: Yes, you have to pad both sides. Normally, in the context of neural networks, padding is symmetric, so I just specified the padding for one side (e.g., see [cs231](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv))